# When i pop controller i get black screen?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

**( i require a present vc not push vc )**

I have a tabbar and a navigation controller interface

my first tab bar item vc1 and second tab bar item is vc2

**push vc works fine this is what i did**
Step 1- I click on a button in vc1 which navigates me to vc3 via navigational push

Next i clicked on vc2 tab item 
 then i click on vc1 tab item and 
then i press BACK button of vc3 what i get is a correct flow of app

backbutton does pop viewcontroller

```
   fileprivate func presentDetail(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.updateCell(at: indexPath)
        self.startLoading()
      let vc3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3") as! vc3
            //   self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc,vc1], animated: true)

            vc3.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        vc3.data = mDataSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
          if let navigator = navigationController {
            navigator.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)
}

  @IBAction func backBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
       // performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindSegueToVC1", sender: self)
    }
```

**how to make present VC work**?

```
  let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3") as! vc3

       vc3.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            vc3.data = mDataSource.shared.demoData[indexPath.row]
 self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove this line?

```
vc3.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

This line is only needed when you're going to present the view.

Comment: terribly sorry i mistyped question let me edit it.. actually it works correctly for push i wanted to know is there anyway to make it work for present vc as present vc will give me blank screen..... do read my edited question

Answer (score 0):

```
fileprivate func presentDetail(at indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.updateCell(at: indexPath)
    self.startLoading()

    let vc3 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "vc3") as! vc3
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true //Use this line so you can hide tabbar. when you push to vc3 screen
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc3, animated: true)

}

@IBAction func backBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```